# Bundling ASP MVC 5 Include Non Bundling File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a bundling code to bundle all of my js.

> bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/assets/scripts").Include(
>                   "~/Scripts/a.js",
>                   "~/Scripts/z.js"));

After I implemented third party plugin, it will generated a js file also. Lets say it's c.js... And this c.js is not being bundled

In my page it's being rendered this way :

1. script a
2. script c (the third party js)
3. script z

Any idea why this happening?
I used the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization v1.1.3

Comment: what is wrong in here

Comment: the c.js is in between a.js and z.js which are those 2 file are bundled and the c.js isn't being bundles

Comment: Your code example doesn't show `c.js` in the `Include()` list.

Comment: @gill23 can you show us how are you loading the c.js file?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to name collision between your bundle name and third party plugin js script. Try to rename your bundle. For example:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/assets/scripts").Include(
"~/Scripts/a.js",
"~/Scripts/z.js"));
```